# Amplification Factor for Trapezoidal Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How do you find the amplification factor for the trapezoidal method?

I have the following method

$$w_{k+1} = w_{k} + \frac{\Delta t}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{3} f(t_{k},w_{k}) + \frac{5}{3} f(t_{k+1},w_{k+1}) \right]$$

I applied this to the test equation $y' = \lambda y$, but when I solve it I get

$$Q = \frac{3 + \lambda \Delta t}{3 - 2 \lambda \Delta t}$$

and my answer is supposed to be in the form $a + b(\lambda \Delta t) + c(\lambda \Delta t)^2 + O(\Delta t^3)$.

Comment: I think your amplification factor for the above method is wrong. Applying it to the test problem $w' = \lambda w$ yields

$$Q = \frac{6 + \lambda \Delta t}{6 - 5 \lambda \Delta t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the geometric series,
$$
\frac1{3−2λΔt}=\frac13\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2λΔt}{3}\right)^k
$$

And don't call it trapezoidal method, it is an implicit one-stage method that is of order $1$, as
$$
(1+1/2z)(1+2/3z+4/9z^2+...)=1+z+7/9z^2+O(z^3)
$$
does not have the exponential quadratic coefficient $1/2$.